# Transfer Gitlab Issues to Youtrack

Tags: gitlab, youtrack

We use Youtrack for our developers, and we have GitLab CE with repos. In several projects we allow external users to post issues in GitLab and I need copy of them in YouTrack. At least initial copy on posting.

Can't find any solution on web. So I guess we need to make our own, but with way is better?

- YouTrack project workflows requesting some GitLab API url?
- Webhooks? I don't see any web hook receiver on YouTrack side. Is there any web
  hook Should U make some thing in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

There're no webhooks available in YouTrack indeed, so your options would be either to use some external service that would copy information from GitLab to YouTrack, or create a workflow that would request GitLab for new issues every once in awhile.

Comment: Here's the issue containing a workflow that is capable of importing issues from GitHub: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-19116. It can be modified to connect to GitLab instead.